# plotting a Bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

[image: dateframe(df1)]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df2=pd.df1({'Jan':np.random.randint(0,5,size=5),
            'Feb':np.random.randint(0,5,size=5),
            'Mar':np.random.randint(0,5,size=5),
})
df2.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Error: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'df1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean `pd.DataFrame`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df2=pd.DataFrame({'Jan':np.random.randint(0,5,size=5),
            'Feb':np.random.randint(0,5,size=5),
            'Mar':np.random.randint(0,5,size=5),
})
df2.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Edited after comment**:

```
data = {'Company Name':['GE', 'EON', 'NGP']
        , 'Sale1_percentage':[30, 23, 27]
           , 'Sale2_percentage':[28, 38, 29]
           , 'Sale3_percentage':[45, 44, 31]} 

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data) 

print(df1)

df1.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: my date frame name is df1 and here we have not used df1 values to plot the barplot. here please consider  Jan as GE,Feb as Eon and Mar as NGP

Comment: I do not understand. In your example you are plaotting df2. Can you give example data of df1?

Comment: please refer the dataframe table I have attached.here I want to Plot the percentage contribution of the 3 companys  in stacked bar plot. * for the comapny GE,I want one bar with 3 colours and same for other companies as well

Comment: Please check my updated answer. This is what you look for?